# How to create a Dismissible Web Drawer Using CDN?

Tags: javascript, material-design

I'm attempting to create a web dismissible drawer in Material Design leveraging CDN and think I'm just a minor JavaScript problem away from it working.

I have tried a variety of things in the JavaScript but am not quite there.  Below is my best attempt.  I've just been testing this from local storage on my computer which I don't think makes a difference.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">



<style>
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mdc-drawer-app-content {
  flex: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.main-content {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.app-bar {
  position: absolute;
}

// only apply this style if below top app bar
.mdc-top-app-bar {
  z-index: 7;
}
</style>
</head>



<body>
  <header class="mdc-top-app-bar app-bar" id="app-bar">
    <div class="mdc-top-app-bar__row">
      <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start">
        <a href="#" class="demo-menu material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon">menu</a>
        <span class="mdc-top-app-bar__title">Dismissible Drawer</span>
      </section>
    </div>
  </header>
  <aside class="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--dismissible mdc-top-app-bar--fixed-adjust">
    <div class="mdc-drawer__content">
      <div class="mdc-list">
        <a class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--activated" href="#" aria-current="page">
          <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">inbox</i>
          <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Inbox</span>
        </a>
        <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
          <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">send</i>
          <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Outgoing</span>
        </a>
        <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
          <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">drafts</i>
          <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Drafts</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <div class="mdc-drawer-app-content mdc-top-app-bar--fixed-adjust">
    <main class="main-content" id="main-content">
      App Content
    </main>
  </div>
</body>



<script>
/*  SUGGESTED JAVASCRIPT
import {MDCTopAppBar} from "@material/top-app-bar";
const topAppBar = MDCTopAppBar.attachTo(document.getElementById('app-bar'));
topAppBar.setScrollTarget(document.getElementById('main-content'));
topAppBar.listen('MDCTopAppBar:nav', () => {
  drawer.open = !drawer.open;
});
*/

// my best guess so far
const topAppBar = mdc.topAppBar.MDCTopAppBar.attachTo(document.getElementById('app-bar'));
topAppBar.setScrollTarget(document.getElementById('main-content'));
topAppBar.listen('MDCTopAppBar:nav', () => {
  mdc.drawer.open = !drawer.open;
});


</script>
```

I would just like the drawer to open/close when the icon is clicked but am getting the following JavaScript error.

```
test1.html:90 Uncaught ReferenceError: drawer is not defined
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (test1.html:90)
    at e.t.emit (component.ts:119)
    at Object.notifyNavigationIconClicked (component.ts:118)
    at e.handleNavigationClick (foundation.ts:71)
(anonymous) @ test1.html:90
t.emit @ component.ts:119
notifyNavigationIconClicked @ component.ts:118
e.handleNavigationClick @ foundation.ts:71
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out, corrected Javascript is below.  A line was missing.

```
const drawer = mdc.drawer.MDCDrawer.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer'));

const topAppBar = mdc.topAppBar.MDCTopAppBar.attachTo(document.getElementById('app-bar'));
topAppBar.setScrollTarget(document.getElementById('main-content'));
topAppBar.listen('MDCTopAppBar:nav', () => {
  drawer.open = !drawer.open;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can add theses ccs and js to get more responsive drawer. Actually, the close button is masked by the drawer.

```js
const drawer = mdc.drawer.MDCDrawer.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer'));

const topAppBar = mdc.topAppBar.MDCTopAppBar.attachTo(document.getElementById('app-bar'));
topAppBar.setScrollTarget(document.getElementById('main-content'));
topAppBar.listen('MDCTopAppBar:nav', () => {
  drawer.open = !drawer.open;
});

window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
   if(window.innerWidth > 1024) {
      drawer.open = !drawer.open;
   }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mdc-drawer-app-content {
  flex: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.main-content {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.app-bar {
  position: absolute;
}

.mdc-drawer {
  top:4.5rem;
  position: fixed !important;
}

// only apply this style if below top app bar
.mdc-top-app-bar {
  z-index: 7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<body>
  <header class="mdc-top-app-bar app-bar" id="app-bar">
    <div class="mdc-top-app-bar__row">
      <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start">
        <a href="#" class="demo-menu material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon">menu</a>
        <span class="mdc-top-app-bar__title">Dismissible Drawer</span>
      </section>
    </div>
  </header>
  <aside class="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--dismissible mdc-top-app-bar--fixed-adjust">
    <div class="mdc-drawer__content">
      <div class="mdc-list">
        <a class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--activated" href="#" aria-current="page">
          <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">inbox</i>
          <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Inbox</span>
        </a>
        <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
          <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">send</i>
          <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Outgoing</span>
        </a>
        <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
          <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">drafts</i>
          <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Drafts</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <div class="mdc-drawer-app-content mdc-top-app-bar--fixed-adjust">
    <main class="main-content" id="main-content">
      App Content
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```